# In wix react native navigation V2 How to pass data from one screen to another

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using **Wix react native navigation V2** in our react Native Application.
I am getting the issue to pass data from one screen to another screen.
First Screen contains the **FLATLIST** when I will select the **Row of FLATLIST** then I need to navigate and pass the row data at another Screen.

Here is my code:

> **Screen 1:**

This code is showing Row data on **FLATLIST(Working Fine)**

```
_renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    const text = `${item}`;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.moveToAnotherScreen(item)}>
        <View style={styles.cardView}>
          <Text style={styles.item2}>{item.name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.item2}>{item.Type}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.item2}>{item.mobile}</Text>

        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };
```

This is **moveToAnotherScreen** function

```
moveToAnotherScreen(item) {
    Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
      component: {
        name: 'ShowAnotherScreen',

      },
      passProps: {
        data: item
    }
    });
  }
```

> **Screen 2:**

```
componentDidMount() {

    const params  = this.props.data
    console.log('params', params);
  }
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Can't you the log in screen 2?

Comment: i am able to move Screen 2. but i am not getting data there.

Comment: 'params', undefined 

this is response

Comment: Everything looks okay to me. Probably check that in a constructor like

`constructor(props){
super(props)
const params  = this.props.data
    console.log('params', params);
}`

Comment: @Bluewings its not working :(

Comment: try this.props.data.item

Comment: @shubham this is error : Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.data.item')

Answer (score 10):

Your syntax for passing the props is wrong. Try below

```
Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
      component: {
        name: "ShowAnotherScreen",
        passProps: {
         data: item
        }
      }
    })
```

Passprops should be inside the `component`

Comment: I also tried this but screen 2 I was doing something else.

Comment: Is there a way to pass data for tabs-based navigation, where no pushes are needed?

Answer (score 2):

```
moveToAnotherScreen(item) {
  Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
    component: {
      name: 'ShowAnotherScreen',
      passProps: {
        data: item
      }
    }
  });
}
```

in ShowAnotherScreen

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.item))}
```